# how to create a fragment in android 3.1?

Tags: android

I want to create a fragment for my application. I have a book that talks about it but the activity is not good at all. I was wondering could anyone write up a small tutorial on how to create one and how to show information from a sqlite database in a list view in it?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a better explanation than the official one:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html